# Suggestion and preposition

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Which one is correct?

1. Any suggestion for what you want to eat tonight?
2. Any suggestions of what you wanna eat tonight?
3. Any suggestion on what you want to eat tonight?

Can you please tell me which one is correct and why we would use that specific preposition?

Thank you in at advance

Comment: The first sounds most idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first is more natural to say **but** with **(s)**:

- Any suggestion**s** for what you want to eat tonight?

Or even better

- Any suggestion**s** for tonight's dinner?